# Make a polygon out of a polygon's hole?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I have a large polygon with many vertices that has a hole in its center. I want a polygon of the hole, the empty space. How can I do that, as it is much too complicated to digitize manually?

Answer (score 5):

This is a two-step procedure with ArcGIS.  This method is also suited for automating with ModelBuilder or Python.

1. [Eliminate Polygon Part (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005q000000).  Use this to fill the
   polygon hole.  For this example I specified 50% as the condition in the tool parameters
2. [Erase (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000m000000). Erase the newly created polygon with the original
   polygon to get the polygon of the hole

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention the software you're using, but one quick and dirty method I've used in ArcGIS is to add a scratch polygon layer, draw a simple rectangle polygon in it which covers the interior space you want to preserve in your source polygon (it doesn't need to be a rectangle, and can extend to cover the entire source feature if that's easier). Then use the source polygon to Erase your scratch polygon. The result can be exported to a new polygon with the boundary you want. If you don't have an ArcInfo license (the Erase tool isn't included in the basic license), Xtools Pro has a free Erase function.

You could also use the ArcGIS Trace tool, but that's more laborious.

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy task for OpenJUMP.

Select the "Create Polygon from Closed Area" tool.

[image]

Click inside the hole and a new polygon that fills the hole is created. Tool works also for filling empty areas between several polygons.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can run the attached python script to fill donut holes and then Union the original features with the filled polygons. From the union you should be able to choose the donut holes by a query of "FID_POlYS" = -1 (substitute the proper field name there).

```py
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def iter_geom(g):
    for i in xrange(g.partCount):
        yield i, g.getPart(i)

def fill_donut_holes(polys, output):

    # fields
    fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(polys)
              if f.type not in ('OID', 'Geometry')
              and 'shape' not in f.name.lower()]

    # loop thru geometry
    geom = {}
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polys, ['SHAPE@'] + fields) as rows:
        for row in rows:
            array = arcpy.Array()
            for i, part in iter_geom(row[0]):
                for pt in iter(lambda: part.next(), None):
                    array.add(pt)
            geom[arcpy.Polygon(array)] = row[1:]

    # create output
    path, name = os.path.split(output)
    sm = 'SAME_AS_TEMPLATE'
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, name, 'POLYGON', polys,
                                        sm, sm, polys)

    # insert rows
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output, ['SHAPE@'] + fields) as irows:
        for geometry, attributes in geom.iteritems():
            irows.insertRow((geometry,) + attributes)

    arcpy.AddMessage('Created "{0}"'.format(output))
    return output
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to rough-in digitize an approximation of the hole (inside the shape) and then use the Toolbox-> Analysis-> Overlay-> Erase tool with the rough shape as the input feature and the detailed one as the erase feature?

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS, in an edit session, use the autocomplete polygon tool to draw a line accross your hole. This will create two polygons with the correct topology, and you can directly merge them (after completion they will be both selected, so you open the edit menu and click on "Merge").

in QGIS, you can use the setting for snapping to do he same task (see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MD77bfOIA4) for autocomplete). No need to merge, just roughly draw your polygon around the hole.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Shapely in Python to identify the exterior and interior rings.

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#polygons